# etherCat communication

Tags: ros, ethercat

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, it was recommended that i looked at ROS for an AGV system.
The AGV's will be used as order pickers and delivery machines.
We are planing on modifying pallet lifts and interfacing with their controller via etherCat.

Wondering if ROS supports etherCat communication, send/receive.
And if so if you could send me a sample, or a link to one.

~Ben

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270855/ethercat-communication/) by [NavyIsland](https://answers.ros.org/users/31892/navyisland/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-13**:
What do you mean by AGV? Automated Guided Vehicle?

**Comment by [NavyIsland](https://answers.ros.org/users/31892/navyisland/) on 2017-09-13**:
Yes, a self driving order picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please have a look at some previous Q&As, like #q260332, #q226843 and #q199494

---

Originally posted by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) with karma: 775 on 2017-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0